# Why does Visual Studio Update 1 want to uninstall Git For Windows?

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know why? I really don't want it to uninstall it but it appears I have no choice. I am using it!

[image: VS Update 1 Installer]

Edit: Apparently it is doing something, not obvious since the Common Tools checkbox wasn't partially checked to indicate a child was selected...

[image]

Comment: Did you check its checkbox in the previous step?

Comment: There wasn't a checkbox for it, I uh... checked

Comment: Okay I checked again, no grey or partial checkbox on Common tools to indicate a subitem was selected... Perhaps it's just going to harmlessly update it? Hahaha. Right. Still not sure I want to press install.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they abstracted all the Git functionality right into the basic Source Control in VS 2015. Read here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/get-started) You can still use Git, but you do it from VS source control view.

Comment: I never used git in VS and I don't want to, I installed it separately and use it completely independently. So why it's getting all up in my grill I have no idea. I'd like it to just go away and let me install the update without trashing my setup...

Comment: I agree, but MS is a bully install that does what it wants. If you have a working local repo with code you don't want to lose I might back everything up first and then install VS and then reinstall Git afterwards. IDK beyond that bc I don't use VS luckily